# Visual Studio 2010 performance testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I am using visual studio 2010 for performance/load testing. I am load testing a product details web page that accepts a product id via query string parameter. I am using a CSV file to pass values to the query string parameter during execution of the test. The test sends a request for every product id in that CSV file. How can I modify the test to dynamically select a single product id randomly?

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of the data source is the **Access method**. It has the values:

**Random** as its name suggests chooses random entries from the data source.

**Unique** processes each data source item once in their file order. When all have been processed the test case will not run any more. Other test cases may continue to run.

**Sequential** is the default. Processes each data source item in their file order. When all have been processed starts again at the first one.

Setting the **access method** to **random** should be what you want.